# JNA library doesn't load dispite being present

Tags: java, spring-boot, tesseract, jna, tess4j

I'm trying to use Tesseract.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI

I've checked if this library is found via jna debug.

> Found library resource at
> jar:file:/C:/Users/pjfg787/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.2.2/jna-4.2.2.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
>
> Looking for library 'libtesseract304'
>
> Adding paths from jna.library.path:
> C:\Users\pjfg787\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64;C:\Users\pjfg787\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64
>
> Trying
> C:\Users\pjfg787\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64\libtesseract304.dll
>
> Adding system paths: []
>
> Trying
> C:\Users\pjfg787\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64\libtesseract304.dll
> Looking for lib- prefix  Trying liblibtesseract304.dll Looking in
> classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 for
> libtesseract304
>
> Found library resource at
> jar:file:/C:/Users/pjfg787/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/tess4j/tess4j/3.1.0/tess4j-3.1.0.jar!/win32-x86-64/libtesseract304.dll
>
> [20/04/2023 09:45:01:273] -[none] -[Inconnu] -[none]  [ERROR]
> read.logic.service.identity.utils.LogicIdentityOcr -
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI

As you can see, it's looking for the right dll, on the right path but it doesn't load at all.

(I've checked, this dll : libtesseract304.dll exists on the path)

Another information : It's working fine for others members of my team with the exact same configuration.

Any help would be appreciated as I've tried everything on my mind.

Comment: i *don't* believe this: "exact same configuration" (you must be missing something...very small or big ..or "corner/border-like":)

Comment: @xerx593 Obvioulsy i'm missing something. But we've checked every aspect of the project or it's run configuration through IntelliJ.

Comment: *As you can see, it's looking for the right dll, on the right path but it doesn't load at all.* Your problem is nothing to do with binaries: *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI* Your classpath is wrong. The Tess4J jar is not on it

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/271) seems you need a VS2015 runtime on your machine for it to run.  And as @g00se said, the dll is a Windows thing but your classpath is a Java thing... from a JAR not a DLL.

Comment: Thanks all. VS2015 and all dependencies are installed.

I've upgraded the version and it does work. I guess we're gonna move our project on a newer version !